# ModuleNotFoundError keeps popping up in powershell even I install it

Tags: python, pip, translate

I have been learning python as a beginner and I came across an exercise where I have to translate a .txt file into a different language by installing a "translate" module from pip. I installed the required module on windows powershell and tried to run my .py file through it. But it always show an "ModuleNotFoundError" as seen in the attached screenshots. I have tried many different ways to run the file and install the module again but the error keeps popping up. If anyone here can guide me where I am doing wrong, I shall be very grateful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOUia.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM7ug.png)

Comment: By default running the command `python3` in Windows-powershell launches the Windows-store version of Python3. So the most likely scenario right now is that you have two versions of Python installed on your computer. Run the command `python3 -m pip list` and you will most likely see that the package `translate` is not installed in the interpreter you're trying to launch the program from.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).